# How to create a new React component with null return but still access hooks

Tags: reactjs

Instead of putting a react component in the dom is it possible to create a new component in the code, much like when you create a new javascript object?

```
import * as React from "react";
import Nodetest from "./nodetest";

export default function App() {
  const makeNewNode = () => {
    const NewNode = new Nodetest();
    NewNode.makelog();
  };

  return <button onClick={makeNewNode}>Make New node</button>;
}
```

`Nodetest` has a null return but does not allow me to call the the useContext hook.

```
import { Component, useContext } from "react";
import { Dispatch, DRAW } from "./global";

class Nodetest extends Component {
  test: string;
  dispatch: any;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.test = "hello";
    this.dispatch = useContext(Dispatch);
  }

  makelog = () => {
    this.dispatch({ type: DRAW, value: Date.now() });
    console.log("new log");
  };

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

export { Nodetest };
```

UPDATE

I've created a sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-wiles-0h2uz but `super()` gives the error `index.d.ts(449, 21): An argument for 'props' was not provided.` and clicking the button results in `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component`

[image]

Comment: What is your question here? `Nodetest` is just a function, why do you have `new` here? I think you meant to make this a class, that way you can expose methods on it

Comment: I want nodeTest to be similar to a javascript class but still be able to use the context hook

Comment: Why don't you just use a custom hook?

Comment: No that is not possible, you cannot use hooks in components that aren't "rendered" meaning converted from jsx to their native form `React.createElement(Nodetest ...`

Comment: I found this from 2017 https://kyleshevlin.com/renderless-components is this out of date now?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? why do you need to construct it with `new`? I bet we can help you find a different approach to do what you need

Comment: No, that article is fine, you can return null when rendering so a component that only returns null is technically valid. but your syntax is wrong with this

Comment: I want to construct with `new` because I want to make many nodetests objects and then call functions on each of them. much like you would do with a javascript class, but I also want to access the hooks

Comment: Hooks are only limited to a rendered component. you could use refs on rendered components but that would be fairly hacky. you could map over an array of a fixed size and render these `Nodetest` components that all return null. this would give you access to hooks. But i'd try to think of a different approach than hooks here. like the component class syntax and `withContext` or something.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

If you really want to use class you can inject `dispatch` in the class constructor.

> Not 100% sure if this will work but you can try!

```js
// Nodetest.ts
export default class Nodetest {
  test: string;
  dispatch: any;

  constructor(dispatch) {
    this.test = "hello";
    this.dispatch = dispatch;
  }

  makelog = () => {
    this.dispatch({ type: DRAW, value: Date.now() });
    console.log("new log");
  };
}
```

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Dispatch, DRAW } from "./global";
import Nodetest from "./Nodetest";

export default function App() {
  const dispatch = React.useContext(Dispatch);

  const makeNewNode = () => {
    const NewNode = new Nodetest(dispatch);
    NewNode.makelog();
  };

  return <button onClick={makeNewNode}>Make New node</button>;
}
```

---

### Old

You can only use React hooks with functional components. From the example that you gave the best you can do is:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Dispatch, DRAW } from "./global";

export default function App() {
  const dispatch = React.useContext(Dispatch);

  cosnt makelog = () => {
    dispatch({ type: DRAW, value: Date.now() });
    console.log("new log");
  };

  const makeNewNode = () => {
    makelog();
  };

  return <button onClick={makeNewNode}>Make New node</button>;
}
```

Comment: So I cant make many new objects as I can with class component and then have each of the new class components have access to context, that sucks

Comment: If I log out this.dispatch I get `Object {dispatch: function bound dispatchAction()}
dispatch: function bound dispatchAction() {}
<constructor>: "Function"
name: "Function"` when i try to run it i get `TypeError
_this.dispatch is not a function` check the sandbox